# VBA How to paste rows on another sheet, so they include formulas?

Tags: vba

I am trying to cut and paste rows from one sheet to the other based on criteria in column B of the sheet1. Problem is I need them to be pasted with formulas on the other sheet and not values. Also since it is filtered the data is not continuous so I cannot cut but merely copy and paste onto the other sheet.

Please help. PS. I'm not using loop because there's too much data, hence the filtering.

```
Sub TransferRows()
Dim lLRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cat"
        .Range("B2:B" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
 End Sub
```

How to copy or (ideally) cut and paste only visible cells (filtered) with formulas, based on a value in aforementioned column to another sheet?

Thanks
West

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PasteSpecial` with `xlFormulas`

```
Sub TransferRows()
Dim lLRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Cat"
        .Range("B2:B" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlFormulas
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
 End Sub
```

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2 Output after running

[image]